# Error: Access to current location is currently disable. Location access is required to connect a reader and create payments

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Integrated [IOS STRIPE TERMINAL SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/sdk/ios) for [BBPOS Chipper 2X BT](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/readers/bbpos-chipper2xbt) using swift. We have developed and tested the system and it is working fine. But when we handed over it to the client in some other country they are getting this error:

### > Error: Access to the current location is currently disabled. Location > access is required to connect a reader and create payments.

We have followed the [EXAMPLE APP](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/example-applications) provided by Stripe.

Comment: im getting the same error, but in iOS 13.
i tried adding all of the location permission in the info.plist file but it never prompts the user for location permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got this same issue and to fix it, i had to explicitly prompt the user for location permission before we even make an attempt to scan or capture credit card.

Also another thing i noticed, If the user's location service in Settings > Privacy is turned off, it will error out with this message.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, this was also the solution. We have to reset the location on iPad. General -> Reset -> Reset location and privacy.